# writing to a file - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and C#. I have the following code which simply writes and creates a log file:

```
StreamWriter file = File.AppendText("YouTube_Logfile.txt");
```

My program *works* on the system I built it.

But it doesn't write to the log file as soon as I take it and run it on another machine. All other functionality of the program is working as expected.

I have even deleted the system.dll referrence and re-linked it to a local copy of the program, so system.dll is also being copied over.

[adding]: I don't get any errors, just no log file created.

Thanks in advance,
Bruce

Comment: So.... what exactly does that mean? Is there an error maybe?

Comment: What error message are you getting?  I assume you have this in a try...catch block and are doing something with the error so you can use that informaiton for troubleshooting.

Comment: The first thing to check would be permissions - writing to a file on a server may require different permissions than doing the same operation on a local machine via Visual Studio.

Comment: Check the current directory

Comment: wrap it in a `try...catch` block and spit out the error message.

Comment: It might be a problem with the rights on the machine. try to wirte it in drives other than drive with windows.

Comment: Any time you work with files, you should have some exception handling to appropriately propagate any errors. Then you'd have some idea what is going wrong.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't write to a file - it merely creates the file if it doesn't exist. Are you seeing the file being created? Can you post a small, complete program that exhibits the problem you're describing?

Comment: There is no error. No Log file is created. Permissions look fine.

Comment: It is getting created if you don't get an exception.  Just not where you think, you didn't specify the full path name of the file.  **Always** specify a full path name, use Environment.GetFolderPath()

Comment: Hans Passant - You were right on! For some reason on another machine the file gets created where executable is running from but not from other machine. Please post this as your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the cause is that it is creating the log file in an unexpected directory because, when it runs, that is the current directory. Your application should probably either include the directory in your path or change the current directory as appropriate.

Beyond that, you haven't provided enough information for a definitive answer. Any time you work with files, you should have some exception handling to appropriately propagate any errors. Then you'd have some idea what is going wrong. –

Comment: error handling is there, but again the log file where error handling takes place is not created.

Comment: Then did you verify your path?

Answer (score -1):

i have got a small knowledge in c, so may be 
i think u have to use append function like this

```
AppendText(YouTube_Logfile.txt,"here you write what you want in the file");
```

Comment: That's not the correct signature for the File class's static `AppendText` method, assuming that's the class you're talking about. I think you're thinking of `File.AppendAllText`, but you forgot to quote the file path.